# Copy file to backup directory preserving folder structure

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell

I have to copy a file in a directory, to its backup directory, preserving the folder structure.
Ex. The file aaa in MyFolder/Test/aaa to .MyFolder.bck/Test/aaa

I tried to use

`cp --parents MyFolder/Test/aaa .MyFolder.bck;`

But the result is .MyFolder.bck/MyFolder/Test/aaa and not .MyFolder.bck/Test/aaa that is the one I want.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209430/copy-file-to-backup-directory-preserving-folder-structure)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only do this:

```
cd MyFolder
cp --parents Test/aaa ../.MyFolder.bck
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can do

```
( cd MyFolder ; cp --parents Test/aaa ../.MyFolder.bck )
```

and I assume that doesn't fit your needs.

You can use tar for that:

```
tar -cf - MyFolder/Test/aaa | tar -C .MyFolder.bck --strip-components 1 -xf -
```